# twilio on pycharm not working for some reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio

Twilio code:

[image]

Proof that I downloaded the Twilio module in PyCharm:
[image]

I copy pasted a small program from Twilio's official website that sends text messages. I then downloaded Twilio using `pip` to be able to use the code. 
The code from Twilio is seen in the first pic, but I added my number and my Twilio number so I censored them.

The code worked on python IDLE (of course I changed `account_sid` and `auth_token`) and it worked. However, on PyCharm, it fails to work. I've also sent another pic to show that I have successfully downloaded the latest version of Twilio (knowing that I also have the latest version of python installed)

Comment: Are you sure your python interpreter for pycharm is the same where pip points to?

Comment: Doesn't harm to check!

Comment: open the python interpreter which you use in PyCharm in terminal, and `import twilio` there, you would know

Comment: Nevermind, solved it. It turns out the name of the module was the same name as the file name (twilio.py) i just renamed the file to something else like twil_io.py so now there is no longer any conflict